# Find the latest entry for multiple values of an attribute in dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table following the below structure:

Table

```
Primarykey: timestamp
Attribute: name
Attribute: {address1: address, address2: address}
```

I need to run a query to find the latest item by the `name` attribute. The name attribute can contain duplicates, i.e. there could be 1 chris's but 4 daves.

How can I return the latest entry for `chris's` and the latest entry for `dave` in 1 search query?

I have been working with this code which returns a single item for a single name attribute.

```
const params = {
        TableName: process.env.TABLE_NAME,
        IndexName : 'name',
        KeyConditionExpression : 'name = :name', 
        ExpressionAttributeValues : {
            ':name' : event.headers.name      
        },
        ScanIndexForward : true
    };
```

I need the above to return the latest entry for each value in the name attribute. Not quite sure how to accomplish this.

Update:

I know what the values of the name attribute will be, so i could provide a list of those to the query but that wont really help.

I suppose I could bases the search off of a time stamp range?

Comment: A primary key must have a partition key, and can optionally have a sort key (in which case you have composite key). You have said your primary key is timestamp, but then you are using name as a key condition. This suggests to me that you might be using name as a partition key and timestamp as a sort key, can you confirm this?

Comment: If you go into the AWS DynamoDB console, click on your table, then go to Overview, the table details will show 'Primary partition key' and if you have one 'Primary sort key'